# error while trying to redirect. ctx.res.redirect is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working with *React* and *Next.js*. I want to redirect a page but it throws an error: "ctx.res.redirect is not a function". it works in a simple component but I get this error in a HOC.
I can get cookies with parseCookies(ctx) so I don't understand why **ctx.res.redirect("/")** doesn't function.

when I try **ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/" })**; instead i get "Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined"

```
export default (C) => {
  class AuthComponent extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
      // 1. GET COOKIE from CTX
      const { token } = parseCookies(ctx);

      // 2. if NO TOKEN -> REDIRECT
      if (!token) {
      ctx.res.redirect("/");

      return {};
    }
    render() {
      return <C />;
    }
  }
  return AuthComponent;
};
```